# Video not displaying during boot-up or in Windows 7 after new card purchase (Sapphire Raedon HD 6850)

Tags: windows-7, video, graphics-card, bios

I'm a network admin, so by no means do I claim to be a hardware genius ...but I'm not a beginner either.

I'm working on a friend's PC for him installing a new video card. He has an [ASUS P5N-E SLI Motherboard.](http://www.asus.com/Product.aspx?P_ID=KyHOsOKWujC2QguJ&content=specifications)

and just purchased a [Sapphire Raedon HD 6850.](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16814102908) When I arrived he was using an old non-descript VGA card (256MB) plugged into PCI-e.

So, I shut him down and pop the new card in (attach internal power to card) and connect the DVI cable (video card only connects via DVI, HDMI or Diaply Port.) The PC gets no video during bios/bootup or when it gets to Windows. I popped the old card back in and installed the 6850's drivers to see if that would fix the problem, but got the same result.

The monitor is a brand new Dell 22" that has DVI or VGA connections. I've tried both Auto Select and manually setting the menu to DVI on the monitor's settings. I've tried a second DVI cable, as well as both DVI ports on the video card.

The monitor seems like it gets a signal during bios/bootup; the light goes solid on the power button as if it's getting a signal but I get no display. Once I hear that it's at the Windows login screen the monitor goes into power-save mode as if it's getting no signal at all.

I've searched around in the BIOS but nothing caught my eye as a video card setting. I'm really not sure what else to try? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: check for bent/broken/missing pin on the card's connector?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it!

It was a combination of having to set the UPNP video device priority to PCI-E instead of PCI in the Bios, and also using the bottom DVI port on the card. After that, boots like a charm.